# HTML CSS align boxes of different sizes

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes a text box and a drop down menu box.
The problem is that the drop down box align so far to the right.
What i want is to have the label text to the left. Then comes a defined amount of space. Then all boxes start at a certain position.

As it is right now the boxes all end at the same position.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

label {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-right: 0.625em;
}

.box {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5625em;
}

.main {
  float: left;
}

.menu {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5625em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="test">test </label>
    <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="placeholder" />
    <div class="menu">
      <label for="peashooter">peas</label>
      <select id="peashooter">
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*I want the boxes to align to the drawn left line:*
[image: i want the boxes to allign to the drawn left line]

Comment: CSS Grids is the best option as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307520/1192479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to make label part fixed with some determined width up-front, e.g. 50 pixels, plus apply text-align:left as Sarthak Jha mentioned. You can also specify width in % and limit it with max-width in pixels, also use overflow hidden or auto etc. In-browser page zoom will not disrupt the alignment.

```css
body 
{
 font-size:100%;
 background-color:black;
}

label
{
 float:left;
 font-size:1.3em;
 padding-right:0.625em;
 width:15%;
 min-width:45px;
 max-width:150px;
}
.box 
{
 color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
 clear:both; 
 text-align:left; 
 line-height:1.5625em; 
}
.main{
 float:left; 
}
.menu
{
 color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
 clear:both; 
 text-align:left;
 line-height:1.5625em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="box">
  <label for="test">test </label>
  <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="placeholder" />
 <div class="menu">
   <label for="peashooter">peas</label>
   <select id="peashooter">
    <option value="peas">peas</option>
    <option value="peas">peas</option>
    <option value="peas">peas</option>
    <option value="peas">peas</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that's exactly how i want it. however i'm currently learning HTML and CSS so i'm a bit new to this.

is px a good idea? or should i stick with %? i'm thinking in terms of compatibility with different devices.

Comment: Well, with this kind of layout you have to make a compromise. You can try with % units, absolutely! But, in that case I strongly suggest that you also define min-width and max-width just to prevent form being too wide or too narrow (squashed). Also, overflow hidden or auto might help. Now, if your keywords in the forms are relatively short, you will not have problems even in mobile screens (typical effective minimum width is around 300-320 pixels nowadays).

Comment: Updated answer to demonstrate width in % percentage.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with grid layout.

Check: https://jsfiddle.net/filipasimao/Lca19d7z/

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px auto;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <label for="foo">foo</label>
  <input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="foo placeholder" />

  <label for="bar">bar</label>
  <select id="bar">
    <option value="bar1">bar 1</option>
    <option value="bar2">bar 2</option>
    <option value="bar3">bar 3</option>
    <option value="bar4">bar 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu
{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
clear:both; 
text-align:left;
line-height: 1.5625em; /* The distance between each box */
}
```

Make it " text-align: left "

Comment: well it does not become straight the menu becomes further right than the text box

Comment: .menu > label{
            width: 30px;
        }

Comment: if i use px wont it mess up if i zoom in on the page?

Comment: Than you can use 13% width if you want then.

Comment: how do you get that 30px is 13 % ? does it matter if i use em or % i assume they are both relative.

Comment: Dude when you trying all this designing stuff remember most of that things are 'Hit and Trial' method. I tried 10% then I tried 15% eventually 13% looked fine. Its on you how you design your stuff. This hit n trial gives you full responsibility and power to you to control you site. And I personally prefer %. Although there are  more which are - "height: 20vh" and "width: 20vw". Search about them, they depend on your viewport. They are even better for designing, or atleast I like them a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left` on your `#peashooter` and give your `label` elements a width so that your inputs align correctly:

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

label {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-right: 0.625em;
}

.box {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5625em;
}

.main {
  float: left;
}

.menu {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5625em;
}

.main #peashooter {
  float: left;
}

.main label {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="test">test </label>
    <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="placeholder" />
    <div class="menu">
      <label for="peashooter">peas</label>
      <select id="peashooter">
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
        <option value="peas">peas</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```